# Inheritance, required super call

Tags: java, inheritance

So I've been curious about something, and it's not necessarily something I need to know, but still a curiosity. 
How do you tell a inherited method that it needs to call its parent method?
An example would be say on android:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){

}
```

Method throws an error until you place `super.onResume();` inside of it.

I know constructors require a super call if the parent has a required constructor, but a method call?

How do you tell your class that it can have inheritable methods, but those inherited methods need to call its parent?

Comment: In the Javadoc. And you tell your user; not your class.

Comment: There's nothing in java that enforces calling the superclass implementation of a method. This behavior is implemented in the Android classes that require such behavior. (Basically they unset a boolean, call the overridden method, and check the boolean afterward. If you called super, the boolean got set again.)

Comment: Elliot, so Javadoc is separate from java then? But enforces certain rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does not have a way to require an overridden method to call up to its superclass implementation. Nor (again in contrast to constructors) can you stop it from being called more than once.

Answer (score 1):

> How do you tell a inherited method that it needs to call its parent
>   method?

There's no way for the Java compiler to enforce this, and it's likely that you wouldn't want this feature for the general case.

- When a subclass overrides a superclass method, it is free to completely replace that method, if necessary, with one that is more appropriate to its own abstraction.  In this case, the subclass method would never want to invoke the superclass method.
- Many subclass methods supplement the existing implementation in the superclass.  In this case, invoking the superclass method is natural and appropriate.

The bottom line is that the developer is free to invoke, or not invoke, based on the needs of his implementation.  Would it be nice if there were a way to force the issue with some kind of method declaration that would cause the compiler to insist that the superclass method be invoked by all subclasses?  Maybe...

Such details are usually implementation details and are part of the *contract* that should always be specified when the superclass is conceived.  Such contracts (eg. such as the Object.equals() contract) are extralinguistic specifications that the compiler is not powerful enough to enforce.  These contracts can and should always be specified in the superclass documentation so that all implementors know the rules of the road.

Comment: There are a few cases where forcing the calling of a subclass would come in handy. I was building a game engine where that would have came in handy.

The thing is though, when working with Android, if I do not include the super call, for instance super.onResume() the compiler does issue an error. Of course I am working in Android Studios, so maybe there are some extra features included that enforce that you stick to their design?

Comment: So investigation shows that it will Android Studios will underline the method in red saying that it should call its parent method, but it will not refuse you to execute it without the call. 
Anyways, interesting experiment. Thank you all

Comment: The requirement to call a superclass method is an implementation detail of the superclass.  Such requirements are specific to a particular class and should be defined and documented; not all superclasses will have this requirement so it can't be enforced by the compiler.  For example, the JavaFX `Cell` class contains the protected callback method `itemUpdate()`.  The developer must invoke `super.updateItem()` as a 1st step and the documentation reads *"calling super here is very important - don't skip this!"*. The compiler won't complain if you don't.